# powershell v2 possible redirection problem

Tags: powershell-2.0

I know this must be easy,
i have the following:

```
ls | % { file.exe $_.fullname }
```

What i want to do is just run the file.exe command on all files in the current folder.
Here is my problem: in powershell ISE console everything works out. The results from the file.exe (console program) are shown in the results pane for all files in the folder.
When i run the command in my shell though nothing is shown. All the results are redirected dont know where.
After that, whatever command i type in the shell i get no output.
Help!

Comment: can you try the same in a console which is opened like below
`powershell -noprofile`

Comment: Prasoon,i tried with no profile and at first it didnt work. But that reminded me that i have been using "ls" alias as get-ColorChildItem ! external command. replaced 'ls' with Get-ChildItem and it Worked! post bellow to accept your solution. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try opening PowerShell using `PowerShell -NoProfile`. Executing this command will open the shell igonring you profile script. This could be because of some conflicting setting in you profile script, if any.